# No route matches [GET] "/account/undefined"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my rails app, I have a namespace in my route file,

```
namespace :account do
  resources :activities       
end
```

My controller is

```
class Account::ActivitiesController < Account::AccountController

  before_action :find_activity, only: [:show, :edit]

  def index
    @activities = Activity.all
  end

  def show
  end

  private

  def find_activity
    @activity = Activity.find(params[:id])
  end

  def activity_params
    params.require(:activity).permit(:name, :description)
  end
end
```

In my index view I'n trying to access the show page by do this:

```
= @activities.each do |activity|
  = link_to "show", account_activity_path(activity)
```

When I'm running rake route, I get this result:

```
  account_activities GET    /account/activities(.:format)          account/activities#index
                      POST   /account/activities(.:format)          account/activities#create
 new_account_activity GET    /account/activities/new(.:format)      account/activities#new
edit_account_activity GET    /account/activities/:id/edit(.:format) account/activities#edit
     account_activity GET    /account/activities/:id(.:format)      account/activities#show
                      PATCH  /account/activities/:id(.:format)      account/activities#update
                      PUT    /account/activities/:id(.:format)      account/activities#update
                      DELETE /account/activities/:id(.:format)      account/activities#destroy
```

When I'm taping directly localhost:3000:/account/activities/1, I'm going to the right page, but when I click on the show link in my index view, I'm getting this error:

No route matches [GET] "/account/undefined"

I'm using rails 4, and everything worked fine until today. I don't see what's happen so if you have any ideas, could be great

Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you have a stack trace from the exception? My guess is that one of the links you're trying to render on the show page isn't what you think it is

Comment: Perhaps try `= link_to "show", account_activity_path(activity.id)` ?

Comment: Are you overriding `to_params` on `Activity` model or are you using any gem doing that (e.g. friendly_id)?

Comment: Gareth: So you think my problem is on the show page? I'm getting this error even when I have nothing in my show.html.haml and my log in my show action didn't appear so I'm not sure it's going to the show action. RichPeck: I tried it but the result is the same.

Comment: @BroiSatse: I'm not overriding my ID with to_param and I'm not using any gem for that. When I create the activity model and controller via scaffold everthing is ok but I have a namespace for the model like Account::Activity. I already did it with rails 3 without problems

Comment: @maxencenoel any luck solving this? I'm getting a weird /undefined route as well when I try to hit something that *should* work.

Comment: @KevinZych: I didn't update this issue but I solved the problem. I was using a table which was supposed to redirect to the corresponding page by clicking on a line. However, an old JS was making conflict and was failed my click event.

Comment: @maxencenoel I added an answer for completion.  Seems like our solutions were similar.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else that stumbles upon this issue, hopefully this will help.  Check your javascript events!

I had a shared JS file between two HTML pages.  Two different people were working on each page and both people attached a `CHANGE` event handler to an element ID.

```
$("#site").change(function() {
    var url = $(this).data('url');
    window.location = url;
}
```

Both events were executing on each page, causing the UNDEFINED route.